# Associating responses with specific requests using Loopj Android Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, http, loopj

I'm using The Loopj Android Asynchronous HTTP Client to send multiple HTTP requests asynchronously.

I'm using a static `AsyncHttpClient` as suggested and sending multiple HTTP posts and receiving responses on an anonymous class. The problem is that when a request comes back I don't know how to tie it back to the original request.

For instance, in a caching situation, when I send a post and receive a 200 OK I need to be able to know which request that response is for so I can mark it as successfully sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyAsyncHttpResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {

    private String requestId;

    public AsyncHttpResponseHandler(String requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String arg0)
    {
        super.onSuccess(arg0);
        // Use requestId here
    }
}
```

Sending request:

```
client.get(url, new MyAsyncHttpResponseHandler(requestId))
```

Comment: This sounds reasonable, I'll give it a try